# How to easily identify who each Nintendo 2DS belongs to?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

As far as I can see, the Nintendo 2DS doesn't have any personal welcome message when you turn it on and nothing on the initial landing screen. So given two identical Nintendo 2DS units, logged in as two separate people, what is the easiest way to work out which belongs to each child?

I know you can go into the profile and check the username but I'm surprised there's nothing on the initial welcome screen or anything.

Is there any easier way to see who's logged in than going into settings?

Answer (score 5):

What you can do, is apply a different theme or background color for their homescreen. In that way, it could be clear. Below you see a picture with different themes applied, and you could immediately identify the owner.

[image: Different 2DS/3DS consoles with different themes]